# Building mongodb 2.4.6 from source

Tags: mongodb, build

The file "action_set.h" in the mongodb -2.4.6 source code includes "mongo/db/auth/action_type.h". This file appears to be missing from the source. Anyone have any ideas where it is located?.

Answer (score 1):

It's generated as part of the build process:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/auth/generate_action_types.py?source=c

It's called from [SConscript](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/5e5bf40a5a3ce6b6ffd643faa50da34ef7d79311/src/mongo/db/auth/SConscript#L7) in that same folder.

Did you maybe miss the step (from [here](http://www.mongodb.org/about/tutorial/build-mongodb-on-linux/) with details about its use [here](http://www.mongodb.org/about/contributors/scons/)):

```
scons all
```